# SSIS - Using Attunity connector with Oracle Express Edition

Tags: ssis, attunity

I've been trying to setup a local test environment by installing Oracle Express Edition. I've got a test database up and running and can query that database from Oracle SQL Developer. I then installed the Attunity Oracle connector. I found documentation that said I should install both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the Oracle Client for Windows, so this is what I did. Actually these are just zip packages that you have to unzip and add to your PATH environment variable. (Apparently the people at Oracle haven't heard of installers.) I then created an SSIS package, added an Oracle Source component to my data flow and created an Oracle Connection manager for it. However, I'm unable to connect to the XE database. The error I receive is 'Oracle Home not found.'

Any ideas? Is it even possible to do this?

VS2015, SQL Server 2014 Express, Data Tools 14.0.61021.0, Oracle Express Edition 11g R2

Answer (score 0):

@Rubio,

You'll need to set your system environment variables for Oracle on the VM or local box you're running the SSIS package if that's where your version of Oracle Express resides. To determine where that is, the directory path should be one level above the bin directory where the sqlplus executable exists.

Here's an example setting: ORACLE_HOME=c:\Oracle\product\11.2.0. You should also set your path to include $Oracle_HOME\bin.

To set your environment variables in Windows, go to the advanced system settings, click on environment variables, add a new one under system.

Comment: Nope, still getting 'Oracle Home not found.' Sqlplus.exe is in C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin, so I added ORACLE_HOME=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server and path to the bin folder. How do you know this? Do you have a link to documentation?

Comment: I've been an Oracle developer in a previous incarnation. Once  you set your environment variable, use the command line tool to be sure the variable is set. If you need documentation, you'll find it under the documentation Oracle 10g: http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/portal.all_books . You'll have to look for the version you're working with.